# Functional Interface vs Interfaces with single methods like Runnable

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

While going through Functional Interfaces, I am not able to understand how are they different from other interfaces with a single method, like Runnable.

We can use Runnable as we try to use other Functional interfaces. 
Prior to Java 8, we already could create interfaces and anonymous objects for a single piece of functionality.

For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ITrade {
  public boolean check(Trade t);
}
```

How is this different from:

```
public interface ITrade {
  public boolean check(Trade t);
}
```

Comment: Using the annotation will guarantee that it's a valid functional interface. It's works similarly to `@Override` for methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference, the [docs for `FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) state:

> An *informative* annotation type used to indicate that an interface type declaration is intended to be a functional interface [emphasis added]

and

> However, the compiler will treat any interface meeting the definition of a functional interface as a functional interface regardless of whether or not a FunctionalInterface annotation is present on the interface declaration.

So the annotation is only there to indicate that the developer intended the interface to be used as a functional interface.

Comment: It is a good practice to always annotate, because if some day someone add another method, with the @FunctionalInterface the compiler will throw an error and you'll be able to see it immediately